# Encontrar carácter '\' como limite en sentencia SUBSTRING SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql, sql-server-2016

Hola buen dia colegas.

Actualmente tengo una cadena de texto de la siguiente manera:

```
registro1\nregistro2\nregistro3\nregistro4\nregistro5....
```

De toda esa cadena solo necesito extraer el registro 5, a traves de un Loop se hace el conteo de cuantas veces aparece el carácter  \n y asi con el uso de la sentencia **substring** puedo identificar donde comienza el registro 5:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'registro1\nregistro2\nregistro3\nregistro4\nregistro5\registro6';
DECLARE @num INT = 4
DECLARE @n INT = 0;
DECLARE @p INT = 0;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @n = @n + 1;
    SET @p = CHARINDEX('\', @str, @p + 1);
    IF @n = @num OR @p = 0 BREAK;
END;
SELECT CASE WHEN @p > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@str, @p+2,16) ELSE @str END;
```

La consulta ya me arroja el inicio del registro, pero al intentar utilizar **CHARINDEX** especificando el siguiente carácter \n y asi solo me muestre el registro 5 me arroja un valor en blanco, haciendo la prueba e ingresando un valor entero como se muestra en el ejemplo funciona sin problema, el tema es que como los registros siempre tendrán distinto tamaño necesito que pueda detectar el carácter que separa los registros.

ya intente también con la función **LEN()** y restando los caracteres con la función **CHARINDEX** pero tampoco me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No parece para nada necesario hacer un bucle para extraer una parte de una cadena.

Existen muchas funciones del tipo a la que te voy a dar que realizan esta operativa.

[Delimitted Split](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'registro1\nregistro2\nregistro3\nregistro4\nregistro5\registro6';
DECLARE @num INT = 5

select * from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str,'\') fn
where ItemNumber = @num;
```

[image: Res]

No puede ser más fácil.

Aquí el código de la función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

**Opción bucle**

Si necesitas hacerlo en un bucle, de la manera que lo estabas haciendo, puedes utilizar una vuelta más para llegar al caracter `\` y quedarte con su posición usando otra variable auxiliar.

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'registro1\nregistro2\nregistro3\nregistro4\nregistro5\registro6';

DECLARE @num INT = 5
DECLARE @n INT = 0;
DECLARE @p INT = 0;
DECLARE @PAUX INT;

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @n = @n + 1;
    
        SET @PAUX= @P;
    SET @p = CHARINDEX('\', @str, @p + 1);
    
    IF @n = @num OR @p = 0 BREAK;
END;
SELECT  CASE WHEN @pAUX > 0 THEN 
    SUBSTRING(@str, @PAUX+2,@P-1-@pAUX-1) ELSE @str END;
```

[image: Res2]

Así `@p` tendrá la posición del separador "5" y `@pAux` tendrá la posición del separador "4"

Comment: Esa funcion no la conocia y el bucle fue la opcion que tenia a la mano para poder resolver esta cuestion!

Te agradezco mucho ,a funcion incluso es mejor en rendimiento!